# CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ASXCollection' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, dll, iis-7.5

I developed a web application which is currently on windows server 2003 R2 and using IIS6.0 ,the application is totally fine ,widely used. Now since we have the server upgrade to win server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 ,i tried to deploy the web application and got the following error in web.config.

CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ASXCollection' does not exist in the namespace 'System' 
       `<add namespace="System.ASXCollection.ASXCollections" />`

i referred to many similar errors on this site and tried few solutions like setting copy local=true ,checked the app pool settings to the correct version ,enabled 32 bit = true ,
even tried to find and add the dll to the project references folder from 
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0
But i could not find this dll.

The application was developed using msvs 2010 on a windows xp machine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try using your object browser in your development environment to see which DLL this namespace comes from. I've never heard of it.

Comment: In fact, I think that must be something local to you. A Google on the namespace finds only your question here and in Experts Exchange.

Comment: That dll was local to my application , i found it and added and then deployed ,still the error remains.

Comment: Please be more specific. _How_ did you add it? _How_ do  you deploy?

Comment: one of the projects in my application is a vendor software interface which has the dlls vendor has provided and few class files by me(it do not have a web.config locally , but the error is coming from its web, config ), so this "ASXCollections.dll" is not directly referenced any where ,so i got this dll from them , i added in the project reference of my main project . I published the solution and then copied the dll's to win2008r2 server.